# PowerShell Get-WinEvent and PSSession

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

When starting a PSSession with a Domain Admin account, and running the following command to get specific events from the event logs I am receiving errors.

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational'; id=25,24} | Select-Object -Property ID,TimeCreated,MachineName,Message
```

> Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

When running the command locally it runs fine or with only one ID number it also runs fine.
I also have the issue with PSSession and attempting to Export-CSV to a UNC path with Domain Admin credentials. I receive the following results:

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational'; id=25,24} | Select-Object -Property ID,TimeCreated,MachineName,Message | Export-csv -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation "\\\UNCpath\export.csv"
```

> Access to the path '\\UNCpath\export.csv' is denied.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
>   The script works fine when run locally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to find a solution for the 1st part.  @AndreyVernigora I've seen this before, where FilterHashtable.Id only takes up to 23 numerical arguments, any more and it immediately returns with no "NoMatchingEventsFound" error. If you cut down the list to, say, 10 event id's, does it work?

Comment: New command: $rdp = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational';
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname=($rdp); id=24,25}

Comment: $30days = (get-date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 30);
$rdp = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational';
$rdpcsv = "\\UNCpath\export.csv";
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname=($rdp); id=24,25;StartTime=$30days} | Select-Object -Property ID,Machinename,TimeCreated,Message | Export-Csv -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation ($rdpcsv)

Comment: Getting close, but I am not able to run this script through new-PSSession with Domain Admin credentials.